# Returning page number in Azure Search?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I wonder if it is possible to get the page number in a document when using Azure Search? For example, in a pdf uploaded to blob storage and a match is made on the 20th page of a pdf – I don’t see where I can get that information in the content being returned?

Answer (score 1):

There's no support for the scenario you describe today. But the team is actively working on a feature that would include the page number when you extract images. After that feature is released, you can set [imageAction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-concept-image-scenarios#get-normalized-images) to `generateNormalizedImagePerPage` to get each page as an image, then use the [OCR skill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-skill-ocr) on those pages to get the content out, by then you can associate each extracted content with the page numbers.

I will update this thread when the feature is released.

Comment: Sorry for the late update, this feature is released. Here is the documentation page you can reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-concept-image-scenarios#get-normalized-images